# JS Получение изображения из input

Tags: javascript

Есть форма html для загрузки изображения:

```
<input type="file" name="photo" multiple accept="image/*,image/jpeg">
```

Как из неё получить загруженное в неё изображение с помощью JS, для дальнейшей передачи по ajax

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5802580/html-input-type-file-get-the-image-before-submitting-the-form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно получить так, например:

```
function getFileSelected(e) {
let selectedFile = e.target.files[0];
return selectedFile;
}
```

Дальше в `html` к `input` Добавим `onchange = "getFileSelected(e)"`